# Most efficient way to divide a number w/ several options

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Problem I'm trying to solve is that we have pieces we need to cut and want to find the most efficient way to do this.

```
var lengthsArray = [20, 24, 40, 48];
var piecesNeeded = 8;
var lengthPerPiece = 11.75;
```

The most efficient way to do this is to use either 2 of the 48 lengths or 4 of the 24 lengths. How would I write a function to do this? Different scenarios will have different values in the lengthsArray.

I've tried the following, but I'm way off base:

```
let materialLengthsArray = [48, 40, 24, 20]
let totalLFSF = 94
let materialToBuy = totalLFSF;
let materialsBreakdown = [];

for (i = 0; i < materialLengthsArray.length; i++) {
  if(materialToBuy / materialLengthsArray[i] < 1) {
    console.log('dun')
  } else {
    console.log(materialToBuy)
    materialsBreakdown.push({
      'length' : materialLengthsArray[i],
      'count' : Math.floor(materialToBuy / materialLengthsArray[i])
    })
    materialToBuy = materialToBuy % materialLengthsArray[i]
  }
  console.log(materialsBreakdown)
  console.log('--')
}
```

Comment: On SO, your question might likely be better respected if you could show us what efforts you've made to find a solution -- then we could tell you where you could improve your ideas.

Comment: @Cat I've added my sad attempt. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compute the amount of leftover/waste that would come from each piece and sort it to find the minimum. Something like this?

```js
// sample data
const lengths = [20, 24, 40, 48];
const piecesNeeded = 8;
const pieceLength = 11.75;

// how many pieces of a given length can we get from each unit of material?
const piecesPerItem = (materialLength, pieceSize) => Math.floor(materialLength / pieceSize);

// compute stats for cutting pieces
// from a given denomination of material
const computeWaste = (materialLength, pieceSize) => {
  // pieces per unit of material
  const perItem = piecesPerItem(materialLength, pieceSize);
  
  // if the piece size is greater than the material size, bail
  if (perItem < 1) {
    return null;
  }

  // how many units of material would we need?
  const itemsNeeded = Math.ceil(piecesNeeded / perItem);
  
  // how much would be left over from each?
  const wastePerItem = materialLength % pieceSize;
  
  // return what we've learned
  return {
    perItem,
    itemsNeeded,
    materialLength,
    wastePerItem,
    totalWaste: wastePerItem * itemsNeeded
  };
}

// compute the waste for each material length
const leftovers = lengths.map(length => computeWaste(length, pieceLength));

// sort by least total waste
leftovers.sort(({totalWaste: a}, {totalWaste: b}) => a - b)

// the first entry has the least total waste
console.log(leftovers[0]);

// emit all the results for inspection
console.log(leftovers);
```

Comment: I was staring at my screen trying to figure out how to rank efficiency when I saw your answer come through. This is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Cleaned it up a little and added some comments. Note that **the sort will blow up if one of the lengths is too short**. This is easily remedied but omitted for simplicity. You might also want to tweak it to prefer longer lengths for equivalent total waste, which you could achieve by sorting the material lengths array up front in descending order.

Comment: That's good. I messed with this for quite a while to finish my answer, which does basically the same thing using MANY more lines of code. It's embarrassing how many poor little electrons I wasted.

Answer (score 0):

This solution calls a `calculateWaste` function for each possible starting length, maps the results to a parallel array, and chooses the starting lengths with indexes that match the indexes with the least waste.

The `calculateWaste` function uses two nested loops to keep cutting pieces from boards of the given starting length until enough boards are cut, then returns the accumulated waste from all boards.

```js
const
  // Defines starting data
  pieces = 8,
  length = 11.75,
  availableStartingLengths = [20, 24, 40, 48],
  // Makes an array of waste amounts for each starting length
  amountsWasted = availableStartingLengths.map( (startLen) =>
    calculateWaste(pieces, length, startLen)),
  // Gets the minimum waste from the new array
  minWaste = Math.min(...amountsWasted);

// Gets starting lengths with minimum waste
const bestStartingLengths = amountsWasted.reduce( (indices, amount, index) =>
  // Populates an array with the index values having minimum waste
    amount === minWaste
      ? indices.concat(index)
      : indices,
    []
  // Makes an array of startingLengths at the selected indices
  ).map(i => availableStartingLengths[i]);

// Reports results  
console.log("best starting lengths:", bestStartingLengths);


// Defines the `calculateWaste` function
function calculateWaste(piecesNeeded, lengthPerPiece, startingLength){
  //console.log("\n" + `calculating waste for starting length ${startingLength}`);
  let // Defines variables that change in the outer loop
    totalPiecesCut = 0,
    quantityUsed = 0,
    accumulatedScrap = 0;
  if(startingLength < lengthPerPiece){ // Board is too short
      return Infinity;
    }
  while(totalPiecesCut < piecesNeeded){
    // Starts cutting a new board
    quantityUsed++;
    let // Defines variables that change in the inner loop
      piecesCut = 0,
      remaining = startingLength;
  while((remaining >= lengthPerPiece) && (totalPiecesCut < piecesNeeded)){
      //console.log(`      cutting ${lengthPerPiece} from ${remaining}`);

      // Cuts a new piece
      remaining -= lengthPerPiece;
      piecesCut++;
    }
    totalPiecesCut += piecesCut;
    accumulatedScrap += remaining;
    //console.log(`    ${piecesCut} pieces cut from board #${quantityUsed}, with ${remaining} remaining`);
  }
  //console.log(`  ${totalPiecesCut} pieces cut, ${accumulatedScrap} units wasted`)
  return accumulatedScrap;
}
```